# Few questions about capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've got a few questions about Capybara. And I might as well ask here since the RDOC in the [github page for Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) is great to get it set up and running. But where is the API or list of available methods??

**First.** Per *_spec.rb file, should `scenario` only exist once? Or is it fine to have multiple `scenario`'s in one file?

For example, in `spec/request/user_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'User actions' do
  background do
    data = {
      :first_name => 'foo',
      :last_name  => 'bar',
      ...
    }

    user = User.new(data, :as => :user)
    user.save
  end

  scenario 'User can browse home page' do
    visit root_path
    page.should have_content('Homepage')
  end

  scenario 'User should not be able to visit the dashboard' do
    visit dashboard_root_path
    page.should have_content('You are not authorized to access this page.')
  end
end
```

If there is anything wrong with the code structure above, or if there is room for improvement. I am open feedback.

**Second.** I notice with the code above. If I have `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` in `spec/spec_helper.rb`, it saves the user twice. This means, in my test database / user table, I would have 2 users named 'foo bar'. Is this normal?

**Third.** I have a form that has an HTML button. When user clicks on this button, jQuery submits the form. How would I test this with Capybara? I don't think `click_button "Add"` will do the trick.

**Fourth.** How would I sign in users in Capybara? I am using Devise. Would `sign_in User.first` do the trick? And would I be able to access `current_user` in Capybara?

Lastly, if anyone knows any "Getting Started" guides / tutorials on Rspec + Capybara. Please do mention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've also switched over to writing request specs ever since i decided that I was no longer liking Cucumber.

ONE) Having multiple scenarios is indeed fine.  You get to use all the other great features of rspec, so I would suggest also using contexts as in the code at the bottom.

TWO) This can probably be solved by using the [Rspec Set Gem](https://github.com/pcreux/rspec-set) And the Database Cleaner Gem.  Also: [The Original Rationale for Set](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/05/25/speed-up-your-specs-with-set/)

Warning: make sure you set up DatabaseCleaner correctly when you use set.  My own setup (which may be a little overkill but is working for me):

```
config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation    
 end

   config.before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end

    config.after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end

  config.after(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end
```

THREE) yep! click_button "Add" should work!  [The complete capybara API](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers) is useful but took me a while to grok.  Of most relevant importance are the actions and rspec matchers.

example:

```
click_button "Add"
page.should have_content("Successfully Added")
```

you can narrow the scope with element finders.

FOURTH) Devise provides helpers.  there is a sign_in helper. read the dox :).  Here's a demo:

```
feature 'User actions' do
  background do
    data = {
      :first_name => 'foo',
      :last_name  => 'bar',
      ...
    }

    @user = User.new(data, :as => :user)
    @user.save
  end

  context "no user is signed in" do 
    scenario 'User can browse home page' do
      visit root_path
      page.should have_content('Homepage')
    end

    scenario 'User should not be able to visit the dashboard' do
      visit dashboard_root_path
      page.should have_content('You are not authorized to access this page.')
    end
   end

  context "user is signed in" do

    before :each do 
      sign_in @user
    end

    [more scenarios]
  end
end
```

ultimately of course, you'd prolly want to split this up into more specific features.  Probably have a "Public Navigation" Feature for all the tests that are about guests seeing content, and then a separate feature for a user signing in, etc.

Comment: looking at my own, DatabaseCleaner setup, i think i could just setup a strategy and call .clean in subsequent calls, but I think as it is is an artifact leftover when i was fiddling with different things.  It might could still be improved, too.

Comment: Hmm, I get: undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000108e77a30>. It cant seem to find the Devise helpers. Am I missing something here?

Comment: oh, yep, forgot:

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
...
end

Comment: in the appropriate section in spec_helper

Comment: This is for integration / acceptance tests, not controller test?

Comment: I put that line into spec_helper back when I wrote controller tests in rspec but still had my integration tests in cucumber.  Now that i'm writing request specs in rspec, I haven't had to update it and it still works.  For exactness, I think you could add :request and :acceptance, or also just leave it off altogether and it should still work.

Comment: Hmm MissingHandle, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434458/failure-error-visit-user-omniauth-authorize-pathtwitter

Comment: hmm..I haven't used the omniauth/twitter authentication part of devise, so i'm not sure about that, but something that looks lacking there is - you don't have seem to have a user fixture/factory/blueprint.  I have a user object i've created in a before :each block.  I think you might need the same?

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer and comments. I have taking these into light.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of capybara, but a full list of available methods can be found here:

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master#

hope, that helps